# (PHP) Find tag in HTML in the main file

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

I'm working with a lot of different web pages and I need a solution to change HTML code, which I can't find by myself. I know it would be best to find the source of the problem and change it but it isn't possible in every case. Almost all pages are made in various types of CMS (WordPress, PrestaShop, Shopper, etc.). Sometimes I have several problems to find, where I can change code to do my tasks. Sometimes I have a webpage, which is blocking some files for me.

I'm looking for a solution, which would work like this:

- I don't know where I can find a source of my problem
- I have access to index.php or another file, which include end/beginning of HTML tag
- I'm making changes in these files and I'm not looking deeper in a code

I worked before in another company, where we were using some types of regex to read HTML code and we were saving it to a variable (string with HTML code) and we could change code in this string without looking for a file, where HTML code was written/generated by PHP.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how it was done. I will be very glad for any type of help!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Do you want to extract the text inside a specific tag? You can use something like https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser to load HTML files and get information from them.

Comment: Can you please provide more information? From which content? Try to post code also, that you are trying.

Comment: Probably, your previous "another company" was parsing and replacing HTML code generated by CMS using output modification. You can do it by placing `ob_start` at the start of the page and `ob_get_clean` at the end of it. You can read some documentation about output modifications [here](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.outcontrol.php).